# How to implement a custom detail serializer on django-rest-auth and serialize it

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I want to create a profile user when an instance of user is created, i get it but when i run the server it gives me TypeError saying that "NoneType" object is not iterable, i created a **post_save signal** in **UserProfile** model:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

my UserProfile model is:

```
class UserProfile(TimeStampedModel):
MALE = 'M'
FEMALE = 'F'
NOT_SPECIFIED = 'NS'

GENDER_CHOICES = (
    (MALE, _('Male')),
    (FEMALE, _('Female')),
    (NOT_SPECIFIED, _('Not specified'))
)

VALIDATOR = [validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[\w]+$'),
                                       _('Only can has letters'), 'invalid')]

user_profile_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
user = models.OneToOneField(auth_user, verbose_name=_('user'), blank=False, null=False,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=125, verbose_name=_('first name'),
                              validators=VALIDATOR, blank=True, null=False)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=125, verbose_name=_('last name'),
                             validators=VALIDATOR, blank=True, null=False)
location = models.ForeignKey(Locations, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name=_('location'),
                             related_name='location', blank=True, null=True)
profile_image = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_('profile image'), null=True)
gender = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('gender'), max_length=2, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True,
                          default=NOT_SPECIFIED)
DOB = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('date of birth'), blank=True, null=True)
occupation = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('occupation'), blank=True, null=False)
about = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('about'), blank=True, null=False)
```

I'm using **django-rest-framework**, **django-rest-auth** and **django-allauth**.
It's my UserProfileSerializer:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(UserDetailsSerializer):
# profile_image = ImageSerializer()
user = UserSerializer(source='profile', many=True)

class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = '__all__'
    read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at',)

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
    instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
    instance.occupation = validated_data.get('occupation', instance.occupation)
    instance.about = validated_data.get('about', instance.about)
    instance.save()
    return instance

def to_internal_value(self, data):
    user_data = data['user']
    return super().to_internal_value(user_data)

def to_representation(self, instance):
    pass
```

When i access **127.0.0.1:800/rest-auth/user** *or* **127.0.0.1:800/rest-auth/registration** and register a user appear the following output:

```
TypeError at /rest-auth/user/
'NoneType' object is not iterable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/user/
Django Version: 3.0.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'NoneType' object is not iterable
Exception Location: C:\PROGRA~1\Python37\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\utils\serializer_helpers.py in __init__, line 18
Python Executable:  C:\PROGRA~1\Python37\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\venv\\Scripts\\asta',
 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Python37\\venv\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Python37\\venv\\DLLs',
 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Python37\\venv\\lib',
 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Python37\\venv\\Scripts',
 'c:\\program files\\python37\\Lib',
 'c:\\program files\\python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Python37\\venv',
 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Python37\\venv\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\venv\\Scripts\\asta\\conf\\backend']
Server time:    Qui, 6 Fev 2020 15:01:44 +000
```

My **base.py**(settings) is:

```
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # CHANGE IT, to use oauth2 by django-oauth2-toolkit : already
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}

REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'backend.users.serializers.SignUpSerializer'
}

REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER': 'backend.users.serializers.UserProfileSerializer',
    'LOGIN_SERIALIZER': 'backend.users.serializers.CustomLoginSerializer'
}

REST_USE_JWT = True
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
OLD_PASSWORD_FIELD_ENABLED = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': False
}
```

When i change `user = UserSerializer(source='profile', many=True)` to `user = UserSerializer(source='profile')` I got other error :

```
AttributeError at /rest-auth/user/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `username` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `UserProfile` instance.
Original exception text was: 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'username'.
```

Comment: Edited for add new changes and error returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the many=True flag on the UserProfileSerializer

```
class UserProfileSerializer(UserDetailsSerializer):
# profile_image = ImageSerializer()
user = UserSerializer(source='profile')
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships):

> If the field is used to represent a *to-many relationship*, you should add the many=True flag to the serializer field.

So a to-one relationship shouldn't have the many=True flag.

**Edit**

Ok so, after the edit another problem became clear. In your settings you change `'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER'` in `'backend.users.serializers.UserProfileSerializer'`. If you read the [documentation](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) of django-rest-auth about how the `/rest-auth/user/` url is implemented you can [see](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/views.py#L146) that they use `UserDetailsView` and pass an instance of User to the serializer. Thus either you make your custom `UserDetailsView` or, if you want to keep the implementation of the library, you need to extend [the implementation of the library](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/serializers.py#L126) and handle the One-to-One Relationship there.

**Note 1:** 
In Django Rest Framework nested serializers aren't writeable by default. So you'll need to implement the [update logic yourself](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) or you can seperate the `UserProfile` update logic from the `UserDetailsView` in your own view.

**Note 2:**
You can edit the `RegisterSerializer` of [Django Rest Auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/registration/serializers.py#L166) and make sure the UserProfile is created there so you can handle the 'nested creation' in that serializer instead of using a signal by getting the data in one API call.

**Edit 2**

As per request an example, quite opiniated trying to follow the package.

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    # Changed
    'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER': 'backend.users.serializers.CustomUserDetailsSerializer',

    # Not changed
    'LOGIN_SERIALIZER': 'backend.users.serializers.CustomLoginSerializer'
}
```

Make your CustomUserDetailsSerializer

```
# Get the UserModel
UserModel = get_user_model()

# Your UserProfileSerializer
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # profile_image = ImageSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at',)

# Custom serializer based on rest_auth.serializers.UserDetailsSerializer
class CustomUserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    User model w/o password
    """
    user_profile = UserProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('pk', 'username', 'email', 'user_profile')
        read_only_fields = ('email', )

    # Nested writes are not possible by default so you should implement it yourself
    # https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # Do updates on instance and save
        # updates...
        # eg. instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)

        # get user profile data
        user_profile_data = validated_data.pop('user_profile')

        # access UserProfile through User instance one-to-one
        user_profile = instance.profile

        # do updates on user_profile with data in user_profile_data
        # updates...

        # save
        user_profile.save()

        return instance
```

Example JSON

```
{
   "pk": 1,
   "email": "test@test.com",
   "username":"test",
   "user_profile":{
      "first_name":"Jane",
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: I removed `many=True` but i got other error : `AttributeError at /rest-auth/user/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `username` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `UserProfile` instance.
Original exception text was: 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'username'.
`

Comment: sorry, it is being difficult to understand how it will be represented in the code, will you be able to do as the code of the serializer and the view will be?

Comment: @Dedadino I've edited the answer with your suggestions, bear in mind, it is quite opinionated and untested but should point you in a good direction.

Comment: thanks a lot, when I wasn't get it I removed `UserProfile` and `UserProfileSerializer`, but after you edited your comment it's been more clear. But I've one more question, it's opinion based, It's better stay other information about user in user or create another class(table) to store it?

Comment: @Dedadino When I was learning Django I used [this article](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) to learn about the Django `User Model` and decide whether or not I should use a `Profile`.

Comment: thanks, [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) is a great article and great [blog](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com)